# Is it possible to use date functions when creating an SQLite view?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Say that I have a table with the following schema:

```
create table events
(
    _id integer primary key autoincrement,
    title text not null,
    date text not null
);
```

And I want to create a view that returns the `_id` and the difference in time between the `date` in the `events` table (which is stored as `Mar 16, 2013 1:25 AM`) and the current time.

I've tried creating the following view with no luck:

```
CREATE VIEW parsed_date AS
  SELECT
    events._id AS _id,
    (julianday(date('now')) - julianday(events.date)) AS pdate
  FROM events;
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: I've found my mistake.
It seems that the julianday function does not accept date in the format of `Mar 16, 2013 1:25 AM`

Comment: Which results do you get from your `CREATE VIEW`-statement?

Comment: Works for me. What is the problem?

Comment: I get a null value when I try to select pdate from parsed_date